# How to setup forward secrecy in nginx so that iOS9 (Xcode7) app with default ATS settings can connect to my server?

Tags: nginx, ssl, apple-ios

iOS9's App Transport Security states that connections that do not meet certain requirements will fail.  Below are the requirements quoted from Apple's document (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html)

- The server must support at least Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol version 1.2.
- Connection ciphers are limited to those that provide forward secrecy (see the list of ciphers below.)
- Certificates must be signed using a SHA256 or greater signature hash algorithm, with either a 2048-bit or greater RSA key or a 256-bit or greater Elliptic-Curve (ECC) key.

I've checked that my server is indeed using a certificate with 2048-bit RSA key and signed using SHA256 hash algorithm.  Anyhow, my Xcode7-built app failed to connect to my server with default ATS setting.  After I set `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` to `NO` in the app's `Info.plist`, however, the connection succeeded.  So it looks like that my server isn't correctly configured with forward secrecy ciphers.  Below is my current setting in nginx.conf:

```
ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers               'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
```

My certificate is issued by Comodo and the setting I used above is also from Comodo's support document (https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/789/37/certificate-installation-nginx).

According to Apple's document, with default ATS settings, accepted ciphers include:

- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

(It seems that my nginx's ssl_ciphers setting has these ciphers.)

And if `NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` is set to `NO` in the app's settings, following ciphers will also be accepted:

- LS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

With this set to `NO`, my app connects successfully to my server, though the reason remains unknown to me.

So my question is, how should I setup nginx for forward secrecy ciphers so that iOS9 (Xcode7) app with default ATS settings can connect successfully?

---

UPDATED:

I reconfigured my server following the guide from https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html.  I regenerate a new DH group with the following command:

```
openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048
```

and added it in my nginx configuration:

```
ssl_dhparam dhparams.pem;
```

But the connection from my app still fails.  The `nsurl --ats-diagnostics` tool still indicates that the problem is caused by forward secrecy.

---

For diagnosis purpose, below is the **ssltest** result page screenshot of my server given by [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest):

[image]

Comment: The cipher list given by ssllabs does not match what you claim to have configured. Go to https://cipherli.st/ and try again.